# Are there fixed size integers in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, portability, low-level

On the MSVC++ compiler, one can use the `__int8`, `__int16`, `__int32` and similar types for integers with specific sizes. This is extremely useful for applications which need to work with low-level data structures like custom file formats, hardware control data structures and the like.

Is there a similar equivalent I can use on the GCC compiler?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

ISO standard C, starting with the C99 standard, adds the standard header `<stdint.h>` that defines these:

```
uint8_t  - unsigned 8 bit
int8_t   - signed 8 bit
uint16_t - unsigned 16 bit
int16_t  - signed 16 bit
uint32_t - unsigned 32 bit
int32_t  - signed 32 bit
uint64_t - unsigned 64 bit
int64_t  - signed 64 bit
```

I use these types all the time.

These types are defined only if the implementation supports predefined types with the appropriate sizes and characteristics (which most do).

`<stdint.h>` also defines types with names of the form `(u)int_leastN_t` (types that have *at least* the specified width) and `(u)int_fastN_t` (the "fastest" types that have at least the specified width); these types are mandatory.

If you're using an old implementation that doesn't support `<stdint.h>`, you can roll your own; one implementation is [Doug Gwyn's "q8"](http://www.lysator.liu.se/(nobg)/c/q8/index.html).

Comment: stdint.h is also part of C99, so it's no longer posix-specific.

Comment: I see. I vaguely remember seeing a compiler attribute that does something similar....

Comment: I remember having this problem the other way around many years ago (not uint8_t on Microsoft) :)

Comment: @Pramod: it exists, but you do not want to use it. It is __attribute__((mode(...)))

Comment: They're only required in ISO if the implementation has the types to support them (which should be most implementations, I know). There's also the `atleast` variants as well for types that are that size or greater.

Comment: @paxdiablo: very good point, but to be quite frank, if you're compiling for architectures that don't support signed and unsigned variants at the above widths, you're most certainly *not* asking this question ;)